# Data not inherited in postgresql table inheritance

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

I have created two tables in postgresql as follows:

```
    CREATE TABLE legals.cashaccount
(
  cashaccid serial NOT NULL,
  cashserial bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('legals.global_id_sequence'::regclass),
  memo character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  credit numeric(255,0),
  debit numeric(255,0),
  transactdate timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT cashaccount_pkey PRIMARY KEY (cashaccid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE legals.cashaccount
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE legals.ledgeraccount
(
  ledgerid bigserial NOT NULL,
  cashaccid integer NOT NULL,
  memo character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  credit numeric(255,0),
  debit numeric(255,0),
  cashserial bigint NOT NULL,
  clientserial bigint NOT NULL,
  clientaccid bigint NOT NULL,
  transactdate timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT ledgeraccount_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ledgerid)
)
INHERITS (legals.cashaccount)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE legals.ledgeraccount
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

However, I find that while table ledgeraccount inherits the structure of table cashaccount. Any data inserted into cash account is not inherited by ledgeraccount. Does this mean that table inheritance in postgresql only applies to the structural part of the tables and not to data contained in the tables?

Comment: you got it the wrong way round: any data inserted into `ledgeraccount` is also visible in `cashaccount`

Answer (score 0):

I find table inheritance in postgresql odd for instance ledgeraccount will inherit structures of cashaccount but not any data inserted into cashaccount. However any data inserted into the child table ledgeraccount will be inherited by the parent table cash account. Further research by watching Meet PostgreSQL by Pluralsight by Xavier Shay section on inheritance clarified the issue.